# Why does this code fail when declaring TMemoryStream locally but works when globally declared?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

The following function takes the selected text in a `Richedit` control, writes to a `TMemoryStream` inside a callback function and then returns as a plain text string the raw rtf code.

```
var
  MS: TMemoryStream; // declared globally and works.

implementation

function GetSelectedRTFCode(RichEdit: TRichedit): string;

  function RichEditCallBack(dwCookie: Longint; pbBuff: PByte;
    CB: Longint; var pCB: Pointer): Longint; stdcall;
  begin
    MS.WriteBuffer(pbBuff^, CB);
    Result := CB;
  end;

var
  EditStream: TEditStream;
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    EditStream.dwCookie     := SF_RTF or SFF_SELECTION;
    EditStream.dwError      := 0;
    EditStream.pfnCallback  := @RichEditCallBack;
    Richedit.Perform(EM_StreamOut, SF_RTF or SFF_SELECTION, DWord(@EditStream));
    MS.Seek(0, soBeginning);

    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SL.LoadFromStream(MS);
      Result := SL.Text;
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The above works as expected without any errors.

However, I try to avoid globally declared variables when possible and keep them local to the procedure or function that needs it, but for some reason declaring `MS: TMemoryStream;` inside the `GetSelectedRTFCode` function fails with Priviliged Instruction and Access Violation errors.

So with that in mind, and the only change below been `MS: TMemoryStream;` declared locally fails:

```
function GetSelectedRTFCode(RichEdit: TRichedit): string;
var
  MS: TMemoryStream; // declare here instead of globally but fails.

  function RichEditCallBack(dwCookie: Longint; pbBuff: PByte;
    CB: Longint; var pCB: Pointer): Longint; stdcall;
  begin
    MS.WriteBuffer(pbBuff^, CB);
    Result := CB;
  end;

var
  EditStream: TEditStream;
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    EditStream.dwCookie     := SF_RTF or SFF_SELECTION;
    EditStream.dwError      := 0;
    EditStream.pfnCallback  := @RichEditCallBack;
    Richedit.Perform(EM_StreamOut, SF_RTF or SFF_SELECTION, DWord(@EditStream));
    MS.Seek(0, soBeginning);

    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SL.LoadFromStream(MS);
      Result := SL.Text;
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Why would declaring the memory stream variable globally work, but fail when declared locally?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that your use of a nested function as a callback is wrong. By a chance of implementation using a nested function in that way works for the 32 bit compiler, so long as the nested function does not refer to any local variables of surrounding functions.

However, as soon as the nested function refers to any such local variables, then an extra hidden parameter must be passed so that the nested function can gain access to the surrounding functions stack frames. And for the 64 bit compiler, a hidden extra parameter is always passed.

You'll find lots of examples on the web where people demonstrate passing nested functions as callbacks. But all of these examples break the [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types#Method_Pointers) rules of the language:

> Nested procedures and functions (routines declared within other routines) cannot be used as procedural values, nor can predefined procedures and functions.

What you must do is stop using nested functions for callbacks. You need to declare the callback function as having global scope. Pass the memory stream via the `dwCookie` member of the `EDITSTREAM` struct.

```
// This compiles now, but the callback implementation is wrong, see below

function RichEditCallBack(dwCookie: DWORD_PTR; pbBuff: PByte;
  CB: Longint; var pCB: Longint): Longint; stdcall;
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream(dwCookie);
  MS.WriteBuffer(pbBuff^, CB);
  Result := CB;
end;

function GetSelectedRTFCode(RichEdit: TRichedit): string;
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  EditStream: TEditStream;
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    EditStream.dwCookie     := DWORD_PTR(MS);
    EditStream.dwError      := 0;
    EditStream.pfnCallback  := RichEditCallBack;
    Richedit.Perform(EM_StreamOut, SF_RTF or SFF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@EditStream));
    MS.Seek(0, soBeginning);

    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SL.LoadFromStream(MS);
      Result := SL.Text;
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note in particular that I have not used the `@` operator to get the callback function's address. Using the `@` operator on a function results in a suppression of type checking. Had you not used the `@` operator, then the compiler would have been able to tell you your mistakes.

The compiler would have said:

```
[dcc32 Error] E2094 Local procedure/function 'RichEditCallBack' assigned to 
procedure variable
```

And note also that your code declares the type of the final parameter incorrectly. It's a reference parameter of type `Longint`. Again, the compiler can report this, and does report this, unless you have used `@` to obtain the function address.

This second error leads on to the implementation of the callback. It is incorrect. The return value indicates success. A value of zero is used to indicate success, any other value indicates failure. The number of bytes written must be returned via the final parameter. Your callback should look like this:

```
function RichEditCallBack(dwCookie: DWORD_PTR; pbBuff: PByte;
  CB: Longint; var CBWritten: Longint): Longint; stdcall;
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream(dwCookie);
  CBWritten := MS.Write(pbBuff^, CB);
  Result := IfThen(CB = CBWritten, 0, 1);
end;
```

Comment: It's just System.Math needed for IfThen. I didn't mention it because I suspected you would know where to find it. Can be done with an if statement also.

Comment: You can also [`add some sugar`](http://pastebin.com/udGkgwUz). Btw. it seems that EMBT is getting closer to the correct prototype of that callback (not yet correct, but closer). It changed since Delphi XE3. Maybe in XE8 will be finally correct.

Comment: @TLama Ah, the joys of mis-translated Win32 prototypes. In this case it doesn't matter so much because it's 0, or not 0.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, it is detailed, informative and easy to understand. I learned a lot from your answer thank you very much.